# [self presentModalViewController:composer animated:YES]; is deprecated

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

```
  [self presentModalViewController:composer animated:YES];
```

is deprecated in iOS 6

so what do I put instead of this code

Comment: you should use storyboard in iOS 6. read this: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

Comment: `[self presentViewController:<#(UIViewController *)#> animated:<#(BOOL)#> completion:<#^(void)completion#>];`

Comment: @kschaeffler No need to use storyboards.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the docs for `presentModalViewController:animated:`. The docs for the deprecated method clearly state what you should use in its place.

Remember, the docs are your friend. :)

The replacement is `presentViewController:animated:completion:`.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
[self presentViewController:pNewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and you will be fine. It does exactly the same.

For offcial information about deprecated UIViewController Methods see here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html

Answer (score 0):

```
[self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil]; use this code for `iOS 6`
```

In `iOS SDK`, there're two methods of `UIViewController`, `presentModalViewController:animated:` and `presentViewController:animated:completion:`.

Main Different in above two statement is that

`presentViewController:animated:completion:` Use in `iOS 5 or lattere.`
`presentModalViewController:animated:`Use earlier in `iOS 5`

Also refer [this site for Presenting View Controllers](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/10/08/presenting-view-controllers.html)